# How to write the jquery "is" method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how I can write the jQuery is method using only javascript?

You can't use any third party libraries. Only the javascript provided from the browser.

FYI the method `is` in jQuery:

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

Comment: You can't. *Pure* JavaScript has no way to access the DOM.

Comment: isn't document.getElementById pure javascript?

Comment: No, `getElementById` is DOM Level 1.

Comment: ok then I meant using using javascript without any third party libraries

Comment: Even if we take "pure" to mean "with just stuff provided by browsers", this is a huge undertaking that is well outside the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: [Copy-Paste](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L72-81)?

Comment: @Quentin there's the new-ish "matchesSelector()" API in some browsers.

Comment: @Woho87 — If you want something that acts just like a jQuery method, then the jQuery source code is available.

Comment: You should narrow down your requirement a bit and specify what *exactly* you want the function to do. You obviously don't want/need to check against a jQuery object, for example.

Comment: @Quentin: I can't use the jQuery code. I'm evalauting some code and I don't want to evaluate the whole library

Comment: @Woho87 — So take just the parts you want.

Comment: @Woho87 well one solution would be to use only the Sizzle library.

Comment: Do you mean pure _literally_?

Comment: @Pointy — Which violates the "no third party libraries" requirement (as would using code that anyone wrote to answer this question of course…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need support for older browsers, you should use jQuery. This should work in IE9, Firefox and Chrome.

```
//returns true if element matches selector or if element is equal to the node passed as selector
function is( elem, selector ) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var matchesSelector = div.webkitMatchesSelector || div.mozMatchesSelector || div.msMatchesSelector;
    return typeof selector == "string" ? matchesSelector.call( elem, selector ) : selector === elem;
}
//returns true if any elements in the array/nodelist "is" selector
function anyIs( elems, selector ) {
    var l = elems.length, i;

    for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
        if( is( elems[i], selector ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

is(document.createElement("div"), "div")
//true
is(document.createElement("div"), "li")
//false
anyIs(document.getElementsByTagName("div"), document.getElementsByTagName("div")[3])
//true
anyIs(document.getElementsByTagName("div"), "div")
//true
```

Comment: That operates on an element, not a set of elements.

Comment: That only compares to a selector, the question requires it also checks an element or a jQuery object.

Comment: @Quentin ok give me a minute :P

Comment: This depends on experimental methods that are not widely supported.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah I'm not gonna write a CSS selector engine as my answer but I think I can do the list thing

Comment: @Quentin well I think that the part about supporting a jQuery object can be ignored if the whole theme is "do it without jQuery".

Comment: @Pointy — It might help if the question was reasonably scoped.

Comment: `matchesSelector`... cheater!

Comment: And the `firstIs` function could just be an `every`

Comment: @FlorianMargaine no it should be `anyIs` but fixed :P

Answer (score 2):

```
function is( elem, selector ) {
    var sel = elem.ownerDocument.querySelectorAll( selector );
    return [].some.call( sel, function( el ) {
        return elem === el;
    } );
}
```

Will return `true` if any element matches.

Comment: +1 for the concept. But it's not complete yet. 1. When there are two elements matching the selector, your method **fails**. To solve this, use `document.querySelectorAll` and loop through it. 2. Bonus: Compatibility across frames: Use `elem.ownerDocument` instead of `document`. 3. A complete solution: Split the selector, delimited by whitespace. Then, use QSA multiple times to get to the solution (note: split is simple, you should actually tokenize it to deal with eg `[value="a space"]`).

Comment: @RobW nice thing about the `elem.ownerDocument`. And as said in the answer, I just wanted to show it's a quick and easy solution for single element selectors. Esailija already showed a good code for a complete solution.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine yea but with some effort you can squeeze IE8 in :P

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I'd add looping to the answer. Otherwise, it's only useful for unique selectors. Only ID selectors are always unique. In that case, your code can be reduced to `return elem.id === selectore.slice(1);`.

Comment: IDs are not the only single element selectors.